# WebSocket handshake Error with caddy proxy in Golang

Tags: go, https, gorilla

I’m trying to initiate a websocket connection between chrome browser client and server.

Overview of my implementation :
There are set of different up and running projects. The load balancer to all other projects and it handle all http requests, routes and proxy to other sub projects. These all projects use load balancers. My attempt is to create a websocket connection from chrom browser to one sub project.

> caddy version : 0.9.3
>
> websocket go library : github.com/gorilla/websocket 1

```
// Starting caddy server to server static files
args := []string{"bin/caddy", "--conf=" + commons.ServerConfigurations.CaddyFile, "-pidfile=bin/caddy.pid"}

if err := exec.Command("nohup", args...).Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Error occourred while starting caddy server : ", err.Error())
    os.Exit(1)
}

//Starting the API server
router := routes.NewRouter()
http.Handle("/", router)

httpsServer := &http.Server{
    Addr: ":" + strconv.Itoa(commons.ServerConfigurations.HttpsPort+
        commons.ServerConfigurations.PortOffset),
    Handler:        logHandler,
    ReadTimeout:    time.Duration(commons.ServerConfigurations.ReadTimeOut) * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout:   time.Duration(commons.ServerConfigurations.WriteTimeOut) * time.Second,
    MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
}

httpsServer.ListenAndServeTLS(commons.ServerConfigurations.SSLCertificateFile,
        commons.ServerConfigurations.SSLKeyFile)
```

First when client reach to the domain, $DOMAIN_NAME such as www.sample.com. Caddy proxy the client request to the https://localhost:8107/analytics

```
https://{$DOMAIN_NAME}/analytics/ {
    tls pem_file key_file
    proxy /  https://localhost:8105/analytics { 
       websocket
       insecure_skip_verify
    }
}
```

There are multiple standalone servers. Following is the caddy configuration of server.It serve static files at the directory in *webapps/analytics*

```
localhost:8105/analytics {
    root  webapps/analytics
    gzip
    ext    .html
    tls pem_file key_file
    proxy  /api https://localhost:8108 {  HTTPS port:8108
         websocket
         insecure_skip_verify
    }
}
```

Inside the analytics sub project, " /api/ws " would trigger CreateSocketConnection() method.

```
//Starting the API server
    router := routes.NewRouter()
    http.Handle("/", router)
    http.HandleFunc("/api/ws", api.CreateSocketConnection)
```

CreateSocketConnection implementation :

```
func CreateSocketConnection(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
        ReadBufferSize:  1024,
        WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    }
    _, err = upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("upgrader failed :", err.Error())
    }
    //controllers.HandleSocket(ws)
}
```

Client side implementation :

```
conn = new WebSocket("wss://xxxx.com/analytics/api/ws");
```

Websocket upgrade error happen in golang backend server

> 2018/06/21 16:53:41 http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:47216:
>   remote error: tls: bad certificate

How I use this secure https and websocket in same web server.Is it posible ?

> web request : 'wss://xxxx.com/analytics/api/ws' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

Am I missing something in my implementation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the API server support HTTPS?  Show the code used to start the HTTP server in your API server.

Comment: I updated question by giving code sample(Starting the API server) inside the main function. Thanks for the giving response for this question. I am really fed up with solve this question. I think the problem is "HTTP/2 does not support protocol upgrade, so you may have to disable HTTP/2 in order to use this directive successfully on secure connections."   https://caddyserver.com/docs/websocket but I have no approch to solve this problem. If you have idea, It might be great help for me. Thanks

Comment: Cannot we use "tls" -> "on"  in caddy configuration when enabling websocket.?

Comment: Because a websocket client does not use HTTP/2, the comment in the Caddy documentation is suspect.  Determine if your TLS figuration is good by proxying to an HTTPS endpoint in your API server.

Comment: Can you give me idea about that complete TLS configuration for websocket?

Comment: Use the same TLS configuration as you would for HTTPS.  There are no special considerations for websockets.